# How can I install the 'ibmq_qasm_simulator' backend?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices, qasm

I'm having trouble running the following cell:

[image]

The system told me "The 'ibmq_qasm_simulator' backend is not installed in your system." I'm so confused. Is there a way I can install this backend in my system? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ibmq_qasm_simulator is a cloud-based simulator. You need to say

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
sim = provider.backends.ibmq_qasm_simulator
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Should I add those lines in front of the second line? I just tried that but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Replace all the lines that say basicaer with these

Comment: It still doesn't work. 'PARTIAL COMPLETED ,  ERROR: QasmSimulator: Insufficient memory for 31-qubit circuit using "statevector" method. You could try using the "matrix_product_state" or "extended_stabilizer" method instead.'

Comment: Your circuit seems to be too big for the default simulator, although it should go to 32 qubits. You would have to dm me me the job id for me to figure out why.